# SQL Determining if Time Stamps Overlap Into Multiple Months and Calculating the Relative Time in Each Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm quite new at SQL so bear with me.

I have a data set with datetime stamps of various activities.

For example, I have a list of projects with the following fields

```
start_project [datetime] 
finish_project [datetime] 
verify_project [datetime]
```

I want to determine if at any point in the lifespan of the project the work spanned multiple months.

For example start_project could begin at 9 am on Jan 1, finish_project occurs at 12 pm on Feb 3, and verify_project at 3 pm on Feb 12th.

I want to determine how many hours were spent in each month for the project so I can bin these time periods by month.  I'm just sure how to implement the logic.

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? could you edit your tags or be more specific in your question?

Comment: @bradbury9 it's sql server.  I've edited my tags to reflect.

Comment: The only approach I can possibly think of is to use a cursor and go through each record one by one and determine if the relevant fields overlapped months, but I'm trying to avoid cursors as much as possible.

Comment: How are you calculating hours?  Like do you calculate 8 hours a day... weekends off, holidays off?

Comment: @Zorkolot 24 hour day, no holidays or weekends.  Just the raw number of total hours in each month.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dimDate table that has business days in it.

For example

```
Date      isBusinessDay
1/1/2017  0
1/2/2017  1
...
```

Then query it:

```
select Month(Date) Month,YEAR(Date) Year, WorkingHours = Count(*)*8 --Assuming 8 bus hours in a day
from DimDate
where Date between StartDate and EndDate
   and isBusinessDay=1
group by Month(Date),YEAR(Date)
```

To add it to your base query you need to cross apply:

```
select BaseTable.*, a.Month,a.Year, a.WorkingHours
from BaseTable
cross apply(
select Month(Date) Month,YEAR(Date) Year, WorkingHours = Count(*)*8 --Assuming 8 bus hours in a day
    from DimDate
    where Date between BaseTable.StartDate and BaseTable.EndDate
       and isBusinessDay=1
    group by Month(Date),YEAR(Date)) a
```

Comment: I see you want 24 hour days. Simply change *8 to *24

Answer (score 0):

With a numbers table this is relatively straight forward...

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/

The following query works out...
  *- the month each project started in

  - how many months the whole project spans

  - returns one row per spanned month

  - appends the date the month started as a new field*

```
SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    CASE
        WHEN months_since_start.id = 0
        THEN yourTable.start_project
        ELSE DATEADD(month, months_since_start.id, first_month.start)
    END
        AS partial_month_start
FROM
    yourTable
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES( DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, yourTable.start_project)) )
)
    first_month(start)
INNER JOIN
    dbo.numbers   AS months_since_start
        ON  months_since_start.id >= 0
        AND months_since_start.id <= DATEDIFF(month, yourTable.start_project, yourTable.verify_project)
```

hen you can use `DATEDIFF()` to your hearts content on the new rows/field.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used a numbers table maybe but this works too.

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable(ProjName VARCHAR(100), start_project DATETIME, finish_project DATETIME, verify_project DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #myTable SELECT 'proj1', '2017-01-01', '2017-04-15', '2017-04-15'
INSERT INTO #myTable SELECT 'proj2', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-11'
INSERT INTO #myTable SELECT 'proj3', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06', '2017-06-06'
INSERT INTO #myTable SELECT 'proj4', '2017-03-01', '2017-08-15', '2017-08-15'

;with cte1 AS (
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN CAST(YEAR(t.start_project) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(MONTH(t.start_project) AS VARCHAR) <> CAST(YEAR(t.finish_project) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(MONTH(t.finish_project) AS VARCHAR)
           THEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, start_project,EOMONTH(start_project, 0)) * 8) + 8
         WHEN start_project = finish_project 
           THEN 8
         ELSE (DATEDIFF(DAY, start_project,finish_project) * 8) + 8
      END AS hours_this_month
      , DATENAME(MONTH,start_project) AS month_name
      , 0 AS month_level, start_project, finish_project, ProjName, verify_project
FROM #myTable t
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN t.finish_project > EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project))
                        AND ( CAST(YEAR(t.start_project) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(MONTH(t.start_project) AS VARCHAR) <> CAST(YEAR(t.finish_project) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(MONTH(t.finish_project) AS VARCHAR))
            THEN
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-' +
              CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
                     , EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project))) * 8) + 8
         ELSE 
            (DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-' +
              CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
                     , t.finish_project) * 8) + 8
       END
      , DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project))
      , t.month_level + 1
      , t.start_project
      , t.finish_project, t.ProjName, t.verify_project
FROM cte1 t INNER JOIN 
     #myTable myT ON myT.ProjName = t.ProjName
WHERE CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-' +
      CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, t.month_level + 1, t.start_project)) AS VARCHAR) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
      <= t.finish_project )  
SELECT ProjName
     , month_name
     , hours_this_month
     , start_project
     , finish_project
     , verify_project
     , month_level
FROM cte1
ORDER BY ProjName, month_level ASC
```

output...

```
proj1   January  248    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 0
proj1   February 224    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 1
proj1   March    248    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 2
proj1   April    120    2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 3
proj2   January  80     2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 0
proj3   June     8      2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 2017-06-06 00:00:00.000 0
proj4   March    248    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 0
proj4   April    240    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 1
proj4   May      248    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2
proj4   June     240    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 3
proj4   July     248    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 4
proj4   August   120    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 2017-08-15 00:00:00.000 5
```